# Use Required in nested property

Tags: typescript

Say I have a type in TypeScript like this:

```
type State = {
  one?: string;
  two?: {
    three?: {
      four?: string;
      five?: string;
      six: number
    },
    seven: string
  }
}
```

How can I make a new type by reusing `State` where only `four` will be required? And the rest should remain the same.

I think I should use `Required` utility type but I'm not sure how to apply it to the specific nested property.

**Why I'm asking. Context:**

In general I have an array of `State` like this `State[]` and at some point I `filter` and `map` states by present of property `four`(some id), like this:

```
const states: State[] = [...];
states
  .filter((state) => state.two?.three?.four && valid(state.two?.three?.four))
  .map((state) => mapFour(state.two.three.four))
```

And the problem that compiler complain that `state.two.three.four` inside `mapFour` might be `undefined` because [type narrowing doesn't flow through scopes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069).

so I need to write an explicit type guard annotation like this:
`.filter((state):state is MyNewTypeWhereFourIsNotOptinal => ...)`

That's why I asking how to make a new type which will have some deeply nested property required.

Comment: There's no built-in utility type to do this. Either just rewrite the type manually or make a big-ol'-complicated-recursive utility type that does *something* for arbitrary types and you'd have to check all kinds of edge cases. What is the rule? Should it search for `four` in all subproperties, making it required everywhere? Or should it only make `{two: {three: {four: any}}}` required?   Or... what? How would you expect it to work for arbitrary input types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this(but this is not a generic one)

```
type State = {
  one?: string;
  two?: {
    three?: {
      four?: string;
      five?: string;
      six: number
    },
    seven: string
  }
}

type FourRequiredState = {
    two: {
        three: {
            four: string
        }
    }
} & State

//Now we can't skip four

const fourRequiredState: FourRequiredState = {
    two: {
        three: {
            four: '4',
            six: 0
        },
        seven: '7'
    }
}
```